# Generate objects from database tables in node.js

Tags: javascript, database, node.js, npm, node-modules

I come from a SQL Server, LINQ to Entities background and have used the Entity Framework Database First approach quite a lot in the past. In that world you can have EF auto generate your edmx file and POCO classes with T4 templating.

I'm starting out with node.js and quite like it. I have an existing MySQL database that I want to use and I have been looking at Sequelize as the ORM, which seems great. One thing I haven't been able to figure out is if there's a way to auto generate models for your existing tables and stored procedures.

The tutorials mainly have manual modelling of database objects like

```
var Sequelize = require('sequelize');
var sequelize = new Sequelize('database', 'username', 'password');

var User = sequelize.define('User', {
  username: Sequelize.STRING,
  birthday: Sequelize.DATE
});

sequelize.sync().then(function() {
  return User.create({
    username: 'janedoe',
    birthday: new Date(1980, 6, 20)
  });
}).then(function(jane) {
  console.log(jane.get({
    plain: true
  }))
});
```

Is there a way/node module that can auto-generate objects from an existing MySQL/MS SQL database?